# Thymeleaf handling null object in Asterisk

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, templates, thymeleaf

I have a Spring boot App with a Thymeleaf Template in which I define a `th:object="${guest}"` and I try to access it with the *Asterisk syntax* like `th:value="*{lastName}"`.

If `th:object="${guest}` is null it produces an Error: `Property or field 'firstName' cannot be found on null`. I understand why the error appears. But what is the best way to handle it?

Since I am using `th:object="${guest}` to prefill values in an form. My current working solution is:

```
<form th:if="${guest}" th:object="${guest}" ... >
<form th:unless="${guest} ... >
```

and this is the part I do not understand why can't Thmyleafe workout in the Asterisk that the object is null? But the `th:if / th:unless statment` gets that `th:object` is null. There is no case in which accessing an attribute of a null Object is suitable.
And if the object is not there at all it is fine.

Is there a better way with less code?
I also tried:

`th:value="*{lastName}?:_"` - same error.

`th:object="${guest}:?_"` - this cant be parsed at all.

Is there a way without the `th:if / th:unless`. The optimal solution would be to do it in one line so everything stays clean. Can I somehow parse an `if` in the `th:object${}`

I could not find something in the documentation or else on the web. Only if *Asterisk* or  `${..}` is null

### Full Code:

The Fragment:

```
 <form th:fragment="guest_form">
    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Vorname" th:value="*{firstName}" required />
    <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Nachname" th:value="*{lastName}" required />
    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Telefon Nummer" th:value="*{phone}" />
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Emailadresse" th:value="*{email}" />
    <input type="street" id="street" name="street" placeholder="Straße" th:value="*{street}" />
    <input type="city" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Stadt" th:value="*{city}" />
    <input type="zip" id="zip" name="zip" placeholder="Postleitzahl" th:value="*{zip}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="code" th:value="${code}" />
    <input th:replace="::csrf_token" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Bestätigen" />
</form>
```

The fragment use:

```
<form th:include=" fragments/fragments.html::guest_form" th:if="${guest}" th:object="${guest}" action="/register" method="POST"></form>
    
<form th:include="fragments/fragments.html::guest_form" th:unless="${guest}" action="/register" method="POST"></form>
```

The function:

```
  @PostMapping("/register")
public String register(@RequestParam String code, Model model, HttpSession session,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @ModelAttribute("guest") @Valid Guest g,
        BindingResult bindingResult) {
    
    model.addAttribute("guest", g);
    model.addAttribute("code", code);
    // form is not fine
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "guest/register";
    }
    // form is not fine
    guestRepo.save(g);
    Booking booking = new Booking(g, invRepo.findByCode(code).get());
    bookingRepo.save(booking);
    session.setAttribute(saBooking, booking);
    return "redirect:/ticket";
    

}
```

g can be null because you can get redirect to this url - to fill out the form - in this moment g is null. I think I could check if `g == null` an then `Guest g = new Guest();` but this doesnt target my question...

Comment: Can you show a bit more code? What is the difference between the forms when `guest` is null/not-null ? The easiest solution would be to always make `guest` non-null, but I would need to understand the use case better to know if that is an option.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe the form is the same but as shown in the example if  `guest` is null and the object is not paassed at all. I will post my code but I think everything important is shown

Comment: so my main question if if there is a convinient the check within the asterik operator if the object it refferes to is null. like I said i hava a (good) solution but in an optimal solution i would not have to check thath with the if/unless